# How to set dynamic height for tableView based upon the number of rows returned?

Tags: ios, swift2, tableview

I want to set the height of tableview based upon the number of rows returned.

here's what i am doing

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let height: CGFloat = self.contactListTableView.rowHeight
        let h  = Float(height) * Float(contactDbData.count)

        if(h > 445.0)
        {
            self.contactListTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.contactListTableView.frame.size.width, 445)
        }
        else
        {
            self.contactListTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.contactListTableView.frame.size.width, CGFloat(h))

        }
        contactListTableView.delegate = self
        contactListTableView.dataSource = self

    }
```

suppose i am getting row height as 70 and getting 3 rows, which means the table height should be 3 * 70 = 210.

how should i achieve this?

Comment: The code doesn't work? What happens now when you run that code?

Comment: the tableView height remains same

Comment: The same? What do you mean? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: i am getting 5 rows but the height of Tableview remains same, i want it to shrink as per the number of rows.

Comment: When does the amount of rows change?

Comment: when i get response from server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133015/discussion-between-jayesh-gyanchandani-and-mattsson).